# How do I know what is the value of a rejected promisse?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

I am trying to use firebase auth to verify a token.

In the reference for [this method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthverifyidtoken), it is written:

> Returns:
>
> Promise
>
> A promise fulfilled with the token's decoded claims if the ID token is
> valid; otherwise, a rejected promise.

In MDN concerning promisses it is written:

> If the Promise is rejected, the await expression throws the rejected
> value.

Therefore, how do I know if the value I got is from the promisse being reject or being fulfilled?

My code:

```js
  try {
    const decoded = await adminAuth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
    const uid = decoded.uid;
    /*...*/
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ err });
  }
```

I get that probably the value of decoded for a rejected promisse won't have a uid field thus throwing an error, but how can I be sure of that?

Comment: The documentation should say what it passes when rejecting. If it doesn't, you can probably assume it's just an error object.

Comment: Or a string with an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin Auth SDK can throw multiple errors such as token is revoked or invalid. You can find list all error codes in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors). You should return the exact error to your client just in case it contains any sensitive information. Instead you can log the error somewhere and return a general error to client like this:

```
try {
  const decoded = await adminAuth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
  const uid = decoded.uid;
  /*...*/
  return next();
} catch (err) {
  // Log the error e.g to Cloud logging

  if (error.code === "auth/id-token-expired") {
    return res.status(401).json({ err: "Unauthorized" });
  }
  return res.status(500).json({ err: "Internal server error" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it throws, then the try will fail and the value will be passed to the catch.